AWS SQS message stuck in "available" state
I am using AWS SQS in my project. I do not have full knowledge about how does it works but as you can see the count in messages available state is increasing .
The messages available is piling up and i think that its not getting consumed by the particular consumer.
I tried to restart the services but somehow for some of the queues it is working but for the last 3rd one in picture shown its piling up. I assume that the messages should be in flight after this "in available state" or how does it works. Also i assume that both columns (Messages available and Messages in flight ) should be 0 if msgs are processed and consumed properly?

It is certain that whatever service is listening to that queue is not reading messages from that queue anymore. Can you confirm how the service is reading from the queue ?
Is it a trigger ? or poller polling at a scheduled interval ?

Answering my own question
The issue was with the 3rd party API which wasn't able to consume the messages because it was down.
Thanks
